# Changing VS2010's default root directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm not entirely sure if this question belongs here; if not, please let me know and I'll move it to the appropriate StackExchange website.

I am trying to figure out a way to make sure Visual Studio 2010 does not create directories in the default location (`C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010`). I have successfully managed to change the settings for the following directories:

- Projects
- Settings
- Templates

But when I launch VS2010, it still creates the following directory:

> C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\StartPages\

The directory is completely empty, and I cannot find any settings that'd allow me to tweak the default location for `StartPages`.

Is there a way to globally change Visual Studio's root directory from `C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010` to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the values under the following registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
```