# Change location of VS Express 2013 "StartPages" folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop puts a bunch of user-specific settings in `C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013`. I don't like this as it messes with my home directory structure, so I have used the `Tools > Options` dialog to move the majority of these options outside my `Documents` folder.

**However**, I cannot find a way to move the `StartPages` subdirectory, so `C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\StartPages` gets re-created every time I start Visual Studio. Annoying!

Can someone help me figure out how to tell Visual Studio to use a different folder?

This is what I have tried so far:

- Look through `Tools > Options`, including the uniquely unhelpful `Environment > Startup` options page.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10390884/1911388), which relates to VS 2010.
- Use regedit to search for the following (in keys/values/data):

  - `"My Documents\visual studio 2013\StartPages"`
  - `"Documents\visual studio 2013\StartPages"`
  - `"StartPages"`
- Use Notepad++ to find-in-files for `"StartPages"` in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0` (no results).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop (WDExpress 12), change the following registry key:

```
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0\VisualStudioLocation`
```

Mine was originally set to `"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\visual studio 2013"`. I fixed it by deleting "Documents\" *and* I was able to fix the sloppy lower-casing at the same time!

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to set this value in the GUI, which I consider to be sloppy as hell, *especially* for a developer tool! So ignore the negative nancies [like these ones](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0975dff7-a0ca-41a9-9ce0-8ea54ffc1a8a/change-default-visual-studio-folder-location?forum=csharpide) who say it can't be done and regedit yourself back to sanity.

Comment: Yep, this is the way (not just for Express, either). Note that if the value of `12.0\MyDocumentsLocation` is not set to your actual my documents path (or has a trailing slash, ugh), then VS will "helpfully" reset the VisualStudioLocation, stomping on your custom path. Keep this in mind if ever you move your My Documents folder. See also my [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21102142/21475).

Comment: for anybody finding this question while searching for the full (non-Express) version of Visual Studio 2013, the regedit key that contains this setting is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`

Comment: This does not work for me. Using VS express for windows 2013. The is no such registry key. Under WDExpress I only have 12.0_config\ and that does not contain a key called VisualStudioLocation.... Possibly because my user folder does no have the documents folder anymore.

Comment: nvm, another restart and the registry appeared :)